# Window (fixed, sliding, etc.) & watermark support in Spark SQL DSL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

Does Spark SQL (the DSL and not the API) support the windowing feature in structured streaming? Something similar in Flink looks like:

```
SELECT user, SUM(amount) FROM Orders GROUP BY TUMBLE(proctime,
INTERVAL '1' DAY), user
```

The only SQL example I found on official structured streaming site was the below, and it did not include a example of windowing feature:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("updates")

spark.sql("select count(*) from updates")  // returns another streaming DF
```

Answer (score -1):

Spark does not have yet windowing features via DSL on Structured Streaming as 2.4. version. Apache Flink have those as it uses  [Apache Calcite](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/stream.html) SQL parser and because Flink is pushing SQL for streaming.

However, this feature may be added in future versions.

Bests

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't think you statement about windowing support is true though. Spark structured streaming has support for window operation on event time (see here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations-on-event-time). Also window support in Calcite is not the same as the window feature in dataflow model. I've updated the title of the question to clarify this point.

Comment: I know that you have even time support and windowing but the point is that you can't express those operations via SQL DSL as Spark 2.4 as I said. Sorry if I wasn't clear